# In what ways may Java throw an Exception without a `throw` statement?

Tags: java, exception, jvm

I'm trying to find an exhaustive list of situations where the JVM will throw an Exception without there being a `throw` statement in Java code. Of course we are all familiar with NullPointerExceptions like:

```java
Object o = null;
o.toString();
```

Also integer maths can throw ArithmeticException in `1/0`, and unboxing a null Integer, as in `Integer i=null; i++;`.

For my immediate issue, I'm not concerned about `Error` cases like `StackOverflowError` and `OutOfMemoryError`, just types of `Exception` (although if there is a list of Errors then feel free to point it out). I'm also happy to rule out calling arbitrary native code from Java. Thanks.

Another way to think about it is - if I see a Stacktrace like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SomeException: Some Exception Message
    at com.test.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:6)
```

then I open `MyClass.java` and line 6 *does not* have a `throw` statement - is there a canonical list of possible causes of the Exception anywhere?  Thanks again.

Comment: It's not really your question, but `throw null` will throw a `NullPointerException too.`

Comment: Augmenting on @Sweeper, section 11.1.2 may be the good starting point.

Comment: I'm confused about the downvotes. Seems like a reasonable question about Java to me - and if the answer is in the JLS then that's just an answer, not a reason to downvote IMHO.

Comment: Are you just asking for a list of all Runtime Exceptions or am I missing something? If so, they are all listed in the official java docs.

Comment: No, I'm asking for a list of cases where Java code can cause an Exception _without_ there being a `throw` statement *at any point* in the code. RuntimeExceptions can be `throw`n all the time, but it's also possible to get an exception without any Java code using the `throw` statement.  I gave a few examples too.

Comment: RuntimeExceptions are those exceptions that doesn't explicitly need to be thrown by yourself. Of course you can use the throw keyword to throw them but what is the difference between NullPointerException+ArithmeticException and all the other RuntimeExceptions in your opinion? If you are not simply asking for RuntimeExceptions or unchecked exceptions in general, you should specify your question.

Comment: The specific thing about NPE and AE that I am trying to ask about is that they can occur without being explicitly thrown by any Java code. How could that possibly be true of _all_ RuntimeExceptions?  The people who told me to RTFJLS were correct but unhelpful - I think you have just misunderstood the question.

Comment: Even though I don't seem to understand your question, the "Direct Known Subclasses" part of the official doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html might be helpfull for researching.

Comment: ArrayStoreException(if you convert e.g. a `String[]` to a `Object[]` and insert something that is not a String[])

Answer (score 4):

There is no canonical list.  Here are some reasons why:

1. The Java maintainers have not provided one.  Presumably, they don't think that would be a worthwhile exercise<sup>1</sup>.
2. Any standard library method implemented in native code *could* throw any exception without a Java `throw` statement.  That is not documented, and will vary depending on the Java version.
3. Any 3rd party library method could throw any exception from native code.
4. You can throw any exception by calling `Unsafe.throwException`.

And so on.

Note that 3. and 4. mean that is possible for a checked exception to be thrown by a method that does not declare the exception in its signature.

In short, any possible exception *could* be thrown without a `throws` statement.

---

<sup>1 - Ask your self: why would this information be of *practical* use?   The Java team are not going to spend time creating and maintaining such a list if it isn't useful.  Noting that it would be *difficult* to produce mechanically.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Because I'm not very familiar with using native code from Java I didn't appreciate that it would be so difficult to create such a list.  NB there are actually several examples at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6 but like you say that is not (and cannot be) exhaustive.